# AES decryption does not return original value

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have written a SecurityExtensions static class to deal with encryption using AES CBC 128 Bit

```
    public static class SecurityExtensions
    {
        private static Aes GetAes(string keyText, byte[] iv)
        {
            var key = keyText.ToByteArray();
            using var result = Aes.Create();
            result.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            result.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            result.KeySize = 128;
            if (iv.Length > 0)
            {
                result.IV = iv;
            }

            result.Key = key;

            return result;
        }

        public static AesEncryptionInfo EncryptWithAes(this string plainText, string keyText)
        {
            var aesAlg = GetAes(keyText, new byte[0]);
            var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            byte[] encrypted;
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }

            var result = new AesEncryptionInfo(encrypted, aesAlg.IV);
            return result;
        }

        public static string DecryptFromAes(this byte[] cipherText, string keyText, byte[] iv)
        {
            var aesAlg = GetAes(keyText, iv);
            var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        var result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This crashes unless I have the result.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros line (which is not in the MS example I used as a basis)

When I use the extension as below, the original value is not returned

```
const string key = "test1234test1234";
var textToEncrypt = "TESTING ENCRYPTION";
var actualEncryptionInfo = textToEncrypt.EncryptWithAes(key);
var decryptedText = actualEncryptionInfo.Encrypted.DecryptFromAes(key, actualEncryptionInfo.InversionVector);
```

What am I doing wrong?

The AesEncryptionInfo is a simple class that holds the encrypted value and the IV

public class AesEncryptionInfo
{
public AesEncryptionInfo(byte[] encrypted, byte[] inversionVector)
{
InversionVector = inversionVector;
Encrypted = encrypted;

```
    }

    public byte[] InversionVector { get; set; }
    public byte[] Encrypted { get; set; }
}
```

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are disposing the Aes instance with `using` statement in `GetAes` method.

Change:

```cs
using var result = Aes.Create();
```

to:

```cs
var result = Aes.Create();
```

And dispose the Aes in `DecryptFromAes` and `EncryptWithAes`.

```cs
using var aesAlg = GetAes(keyText, new byte[0]);
using var aesAlg = GetAes(keyText, iv);
```